# right use of fromIntegral and mismatched brackets

Tags: haskell

```
def :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
def (x, y) 
| x == 0 && y == 0  = (0, 1, 0)
| otherwise = ( fromIntegral x/34, y, a )
  where a = x + y
```

always getting the message incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets. even tried to left out the a variable with the where structure. Also i am not sure if i did the declaration and the fromIntegral correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indent the guards more than the surrounding context (which in this case is `def`). You also have a few type errors, most of which can be dealt with by liberal application of `fromIntegral`. The only other obvious thing I spot is that `00` is not a triple -- perhaps you meant `(0, 0, 0)` instead? But if you did, it seems the second clause is going to return that anyway; so perhaps you don't need any guards at all.

You also might consider changing the type to `def :: Double -> Double -> (Double, Double, Double)` and leaving it to the caller to handle converting from `Int` to `Double`, though that is a design choice that depends a lot on the meaning of `def` and its role in your larger system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i tried to indent the guards mor to the right, but it is not working. 
when x and y = 0 , it should give out 0,0,0,0. Is it even possible with the comma?

Comment: The commas are part of the tuple construction, so they are required to construct a tuple.

Comment: obviously, the declaration def :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) is not right. But I like the results to be Integer. How do I do this?

Comment: @letter There are functions `round, floor, ceiling :: Double -> Integer`. Perhaps one of them meets your needs.